# Can I deploy a .NET 4.5 app to App Engine?

Tags: .net, google-app-engine, .net-4.5

My question is about deploying a .NET 4.5 app to **App Engine**:

Does **App Engine** support it?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy .NET applications using the App Engine Flexible Environment.

[This guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/quickstart) should help you get started. Other useful documentation can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/).

Answer (score 0):

No. You can only deploy .NET Core on App Engine. The 4.x Framework is not supported. The only way to do this, is to create a new netcoreapp ASP.NET web site and port your code.